# Hide an element if the next one is on a different line

Tags: css, css-float

I need to display an address on a webpage, and it needs to be displayed as following

> Street Number, PostalCode City

However, if the address is too long to fit on one line, it needs to be displayed as following

> Street Number
>
> PostalCode City

Note the lack of a comma. I already figured out how to do the breaking on that point, but I'm stuck on the comma. Is there any way at all to do this just in CSS, or with minimal JS?

Here's what I have already

HTML:

```
<div class="floatLeft">
   Street<span>&nbsp;</span>12<span>,&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class="floatLeft">9000<span>&nbsp;</span>Gent</div>
```

CSS:

```
.floatLeft {
   float:left;
}
```

And a working JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7w70fff1/1/

Comment: This can't - to the best of my knowledge - be done with CSS, since you'd be styling a sibling based on the position of its following sibling and there's no CSS selector for 'different line' *or* 'previous sibling'. This could be done with JavaScript, but even then I'd suggest changing your HTML, since it seems - to me -  very strange (though it may make perfect sense in your use case).

Comment: The HTML can be changed. It worked fine for the first part of the use case (i.e. splitting at a specific point), but it's possible there are other solutions that work just as well. But I'm not sure if this requirement is even possible to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this. The comma is positioned absolutely, so that when the second div wraps, it is positioned to the left of the container viewport, where it is hidden.

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container::after {
  clear: both;
}
.floatLeft {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.floatLeft:first-child {
  margin-right: 1ch
}
.floatLeft:not(:first-child) span:first-child {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0;
  content: ',\00A0';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="floatLeft">AnAwfullyLongStreetName<span>&nbsp;</span>12
  </div>
  <div class="floatLeft"><span>,&nbsp;</span>9000<span>&nbsp;</span>Gent</div>
</div>
```